# insert values into database table every two minutes

Tags: php, mysql

How to insert values into database table every two minutes?

I have code that doing every second that will explode my mysql database, which I do not want it happen. So I want to set it to 2 min.

```
$query="INSERT INTO $tablename VALUES ($temp,now())";
```

Here is the code for every second sent it to my databse.

and the code below is to set it two min , but is doesn't work

```
$timestamp=DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE);
$query="INSERT INTO $tablename VALUES ($temp,$timestamp)";
```

Some help me . thanks

Comment: You're only changing _the value being stored_, not the schedule itself. Where's the code that schedules this query's execution?

Comment: Maybe you can explain to us why you need to insert data every 2 minutes ?

Comment: I want temperature data send it to my database every 2 minutes,not every second

Comment: @Yang that actually seems to be like valid reason to put data in DB every two minutes. You need to set up some kind of task scheduling application that will run your script every two minutes. Php scripts generally run in an instant, and once they finish, they're finished, there's no way to keep them running forever. Task scheduling application under windows is task scheduler, under linux it's called Cron, look it up, you will find tutorials.

Comment: So I'm asking again: How is this code _triggered_? What's the procedure that actually calls the above? Is it a cron job? You do it manually from the command line? Do you have to constantly press [F5] on a browser window _every seond_? Is there a remote daemom that `wget`s it?

Comment: the data comes from arduino. so the temperature changed every second. I have to constantly press refresh to see the new data on my mac. Hope that answer your question

Comment: @enrey  where is task scheduler under mac ? I am running program on mac

Comment: @Yang You have to constantly refresh in order to _see the data_ (ie fetc them from the db) or in order to _call the script that updates the db_? Do a simple test: When you wake up in the morning and open a browser on your mac, do you see data written _during the night_?

Comment: @Yang You need to do some client-side refreshing, it's not hard. [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) is probably the easiest way.

Comment: @tadman I will try them .

Comment: @Yang I don't know, but I don't even know how all this stuff is connected, whether the PHP is on the server and other server is sending the data in via http requests, or you're sending data through http requests or some local application or server app is sending requests or whether you're just refreshing a website or what.. If some other application is sending the data in every second, why not slowing that application? Try to edit the question and reword it so we get some idea about what's where and what does what and what is all this about. Currently, I'm quite confused about what you need.

Comment: @enrey look at this website. I am doing the almost the same as he did http://www.jfkreuter.com/?p=9    that is the data I want to send it from arduino to mysql. but I would like to send it every five min or ten mins

Comment: @geomagas  would be better to look at this website. then you know what i am doing and why i want to set it up 5 min... http://www.jfkreuter.com/?p=9

Comment: I think I got it .. I delay 3 min at arduino .. so the arduino data post every 3 mins..

Comment: So your php script _had nothing to do with it after all_. Glad you found a solution. _(and I rest my case...)_

Comment: @geomagas seems like, I looked at the website, there's some unindented blob of something that looks like C++ with `delay(500)` near the end.. Kind of obvious.. So this has nothing to do with PHP.. This would be kind of annoying if those guys were programmers, but since they most probably aren't... @Yang My hat down, soldering pieces together and hacking several languages without knowing what you're doing... that's what I call real hacking : ))

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my answer will not satisfy you but it's a mistake to make a task every 2 minute with a web framework. When you close your web browser, the task will not continue. This kind of daemon task must be done with CRONTAB.

Comment: This is not an answer. It belongs to a _comment_. So I think it satisfies pretty much _noone_.

Comment: @geomagas In fairness, it is the correct answer. OP is completely off course and his comment about wanting it to run every 2 minutes points towards the need for crontab or Windows task scheduler. Saying that it satisfied nobody is wrong imo.

Comment: Maybe, I admit I hesitated to write as a comment

Comment: I edited my answer. I deleted my question in my answer and I writed it in comments. Sorry

Comment: @WayneWhitty 1) The fact that this code is only triggered by a web browser request is implied _nowhere_ 2) the last sentence makes the whole post rather _a clarification question_ 3) this has nothing to do with your notion of fairness, this is about addressing _the issue_ -- instead, he is _altering the issue to fit his "answer"_.

Comment: @geomagas I agree. However, I'm stick of people on Stackoverflow giving the `technically correct` answer instead of the answer that will actually push the person in the right direction. OP wants to execute the code in question every two minutes. Crontab is the perfect tool for that.

Comment: @geomagas For me it's the correct absolute answer. The technically correct answer is the one of Kleskowy.

Comment: @WayneWhitty OTOH I'm sick of people wanting to _"push the person in the right direction"_ -- but that's just me refusing to pretend I'm the _Custodian of Right and Wrong_. SO is a _technical reference site_ and it's doing well at it. People love it for that. It's a Q&A, so I beleive every _A_ should strictly address the _Q_. And again, nobody implied he's not already using crontab or something along the lines of.

Comment: @geomagas You're pretending like this is a matter of opinion when we both know that a cron job is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @WayneWhitty No, you fail to understand I'm saying the exact opposite: _I refuse to express a biased opinion_, I'm only trying to address the OP's issue _without judging his reasons_. Proof: _"a cron job is the correct way to do it"_ __For the third time, nobody said he's not already doing it!!!__

Comment: @geomagas His last comment just confirms the need for a cron job.

Comment: @WayneWhitty No, it just confirms you "pushed him in the right direction". I'm gonna watch this, I'm curious.

Comment: @geomagas We fight for silliness. If you have a better answer, write it​​. We'll see what response the author chooses. All I want is that Yang found a good answer for him.

Comment: @Ludovic Don't demote my arguments to _silliness_, don't even try to. And don't change the subject, I obvously haven't provided an answer yet, because _I don't have enough input to come up with a definitive one!_ See, I'm not biased by any prejudice, I'm waiting for clarifications.

Comment: @Ludovic As for the "good answers", the "technically correct" is not so "correct" after all, as you can see... Let's wait to see what happens with the "absolutely correct" one... One _Fast Gun_ down, one to go...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from completely wrong approach (you need cron daemon to control tasks running every n minutes) , possibly what you're trying to do is to use [mysql's date_sub()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```
$mysqlString= 'DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)'; //this makes it a string
$query="INSERT INTO $tablename VALUES ($temp, {$mysqlString})";
echo $query;
```